# AttributeError: module 'pygal' has no attribute 'Worldmap'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygal

I'm trying to:

```
import pygal
wm = pygal.Worldmap()
```

but it raises:

```
AttributeError: module 'pygal' has no attribute 'Worldmap'
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are probably looking at old documentation from what I can tell. The most recent [docs](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/maps/pygal_maps_world.html) state that you first need to install the map plugin with:

```
pip install pygal_maps_world
```

and then use it as:

```
import pygal
mm = pygal.maps.world.World()
```